# initial commit of a project with dependencies already having .git

Tags: git, github, laravel-5

I am new to the use of github.
I am working locally on a Laravel project (not from homestead, but with Laragon)
Now, I wanted to put it on github.  I would prefer using github desktop, but if command lines are necessary, i will use them.

I made a repo in github, cloned it, and copy/pasted my project in it.
when I tried to make the commit -- using github desktop -- I got the following messsage :

> could not commit submodules
>   vendor/doctrine/dbal
>   add them as submodule from git shell or remove their .git folder to add them as regular directories instead

the dbal folder, indeed, has a .gitattribute file.
Do I have to work this out manually ?  there are many .gitattribute files from many dependencies in the Laravel framework.
Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Looking at my problem, I found that there is a .gitignore file at the root of my project with the /vendor instruction in it.
All of the vendor folder should be ignored... but the dbal folder contains a .gitmodules file

To quote the webpage mjb recommends me : "If the technological context allows for packaging and formal dependency management, you should absolutely go this route."
However, authors of some dependencies that are otherwise managed by Composer have chosen the submodule route.  This makes the context of my problem more clear, I hope.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Laravel projects, but I do know you'll have to choose one or the other option. Git treats the information in each `.git/` folder as truth. To dig really deeply into submodules, [give this a read](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-submodules-34c65e940407#.knvbwowbk).

The TL;DR in my opinion is, if you don't want to manage submodules and updating these repositories as separate sub-modules, then:

```
find . -type d -name ".git"
rm -rf .git/ # for each of the folders listed that are not ./.git
```